# numpy linspace -- keep only odd elements

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a faster way to get every odd element from `numpy.linspace`? What I'm currently doing is the obvious:

```
x = np.linspace(start,stop,n)[1::2]
```

as an explicit example:

```
>>> np.linspace(0,10,21)[1::2]
array([ 0.5,  1.5,  2.5,  3.5,  4.5,  5.5,  6.5,  7.5,  8.5,  9.5])
```

Comment: you could do the "math" instead and go for `np.linspace(0.5,9.5,10)` assuming you do not need the full thing as well.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis True. Sometimes the simplest solutions are so hard to see :D Still, I guess I would need some kind of conditional to discriminate between even and odd `n`.

Comment: @ThomasKuehn Regardless of the `n` being odd or even, `linspace` creates an _arithmetic progression_. Choosing every k_th element from that progression will create another progression that could have been generated with `linspace` to begin with. So, the question is how one links this _k_ with `start`, `stop` and `n`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis thanks, I see the light now.

Comment: @ThomasKuehn Happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the mapping function for the way that you have used your variables. Keep the same variable values for the same results. Hope this helps!

```
x = np.linspace(start,stop,n)[1::2]
```

to

```
x = np.linspace(start+stop/(n-1),stop-stop/(n-1), (n-1)/2)
```

Comment: Works like expected and indeed speeds up my code a bit. Should have been able to solve this myself, but thanks for your help.